# How to change gradle target sdk in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2, build.gradle

After I run the `ionic cordova build android --release` command, the AndroidManifest.xml shows `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />`.

However, Google Play won't let me update the app because it said that my target SDK is set to 22 (and not 26 as set in the manifest) which is lower than my previous version.

When I checked the AndroidManifest.xml in Android Studio, the Merged Manifest tab shows `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />` and log said the targetSdkVersion value is added by Gradle.

What do I need to do to set the target SDK to 23 or higher?

Answer (score 0):

execute this command on CMD or set up this into environment variable.

```
set ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_cdvCompileSdkVersion=android-26 // mention which version you want to build
  set ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_cdvBuildToolsVersion=26.0.1 //mention which version you want to build
```

I hope you are using windows

Comment: how to do this on mac? Thanks.